# Setting CORS only Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have set a CORS policy on my bucket to allow requests from my cloud functions,

```
gsutil cors get gs://my-project.appspot.com
```

returns:

```
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, 
"method": ["GET"], 
"origin": ["https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net"], 
"responseHeader": ["Content-Type"]}]
```

However, when I try to access a resource from my cloud function, I get the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://storage.cloud.google.com/my-project.appspot.com/mydata.csv'
>   from origin 'https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net' has
>   been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
>   is present on the requested resource.

I am not sure where to go from here. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it work with `https://storage.googleapis.com/my-project.appspot.com/mydata.csv`?

Comment: That worked, thank you!